# "And you, me" Valid or Invalid?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

I was having a conversation with a friend and happened to say "You know a lot about me."

She responded with "And you, me." I've heard this construction before, meaning something along the lines of *and same with you to me*. However, I'm wondering is this is a grammatically valid construction? It seems too minimalistic to be valid, but it conveys the idea perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an acceptable sentence construction.

From [TERMIUM Plus](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng) (the Government of Canada’s terminology and linguistic data bank):

> A comma may be used to indicate that repeated words have been omitted from the second clause in a compound sentence:
>
> The African countries sent six representatives; the Asian countries, five.

In your example, the comma is used in a second sentence immediately after the first—rather than in a second clause in a compound sentence—but the same principle applies.

The exchange can be thought of as:

> You know a lot about me.
> And you[,] [know a lot about] me.